# Adding SCNNode to scene.rootNode changes rotation point

Tags: scenekit

I am working on my first SceneKit app which is a Galaxy viewer. It shows where various deep sky objects are located in the Galaxy.  This is going well, however if I add objects that are far from the Galaxy, something is being automatically changed about the rotation point or possibly the projection.  Here is how I'm setting things up (fairly standard I think):

```
    // Create and positon the camera
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: Float(2 * GAL_IMAGE_WIDTH_IN_LIGHT_YEARS) * Float(sceneScale))
    camera.automaticallyAdjustsZRange = true
    camera.fieldOfView = 35

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // Create and position the galactic plane
    let galaxyGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(GAL_IMAGE_WIDTH_IN_LIGHT_YEARS * sceneScale), height: CGFloat(GAL_IMAGE_WIDTH_IN_LIGHT_YEARS * sceneScale))
    let galaxyNode = SCNNode(geometry: galaxyGeometry)
    galaxyNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

    // Create material for galactic plane
    let galaxyImage = UIImage.init(named: "Galaxy" )
    let galaxyMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    galaxyMaterial.transparency = 0.98
    galaxyMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    galaxyMaterial.diffuse.contents = galaxyImage
    galaxyGeometry.materials = [galaxyMaterial]

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(galaxyNode)
```

I can add lots of nearby deep sky objects and the view will continue to rotate around the galactic core.  However, if I add something that greater than about1.5 galaxy diameters away, all the sudden something is changed such I no longer rotate around the core.

I've poked around looking at the rootNode's position and transformation and don't see anything amiss there.  Any ideas on what is getting changed?

Comment: I've been playing around with this further.  It seems that if I pan the view *before* adding the distant deep sky objects then all is fine.  I am using "allowsCameraControl" and when I pan, the system creates a new pointOfView that is a copy of the initial camera node.  Not sure why this side effect would cause things to work.  Does anyone know how to force the creation of the new pointOfView so I can do that before adding the objects to the scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a solution that seems to work for me.  Even though the camera, by default, is looking down the z axis at (0, 0), if I explicitly set the target of the defaultCameraController to the node I've placed there, it seems to work even when placing other nodes far away from the galaxy node.

```
    galaxyView.allowsCameraControl = true
    galaxyView.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitAngleMapping
    galaxyView.defaultCameraController.target = galaxyNode.position
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using SceneKit's automatic camera behaviour via `allowsCameraControl`. You can better customise this behaviour with the [`SCNCameraController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncameracontroller) class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this seems to be something screwed up with the coordinate system and/or pivot point.  I don't see how controlling the camera myself will fix this.  I wish to use the default behavior.